# helmholtz decomposition - Can't follow steps

Tags: proof-verification

I'm trying to follow the proof for the derivation of helmholtz decomposition from wikipedia, however, I can't figure out how the negative sign changes into a positive.

If some one can help that would be great. The attached picture shows where I'm stuck

[image: https://i.imgur.com/yWjdt7b.png]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition

Comment: Hey, you should type the relevant part in LaTeX, see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I suspect its because $$\nabla \times (v f) = \nabla f \times v = - v \times \nabla f$$ for any constant vector $v$. In your case $v = F(r')$ in the last integral.

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because $$\nabla \times (vf) = \nabla f \times v = -v \times \nabla f$$
for any constant vector $v$. In your case, $v=F(r')$ in the last integral.